# Who are these very unusual superheroes on this 2nd hand T-shirt?

Tags: character-identification, super-hero

I saw this T-shirt in a small shop of 2nd hand stuff in Taipei. There are all kinds of T-shirts cycling around Asia with creative/weird pictures and misspelled words, but this one looks really intentionally and carefully crafted (at least compared to the rest), not just thrown together from absolute random internet images.

Can someone explain this? Is it something everybody knows except me, or genuinely weird?

[image: Strange Superhero T-shirt in Taipei]

Comment: Who the *heroes* are is pretty obvious....what else are you asking?

Comment: @Paulie_D I can see an obvious similarity with 2, maybe 3 of the costumes myself, but I don't know if this group is actually a "thing" beyond that. Similarly, I can recognize a box of fries and a fast food drink, but that also describes Aqua Teen Hunger Force.

Comment: I see what you did there. Also, I hope you bought it.

Comment: While the resemblance is the least obvious one, from the context, I'd assume the man in the bunny pajamas represents Bugs Bunny.

Comment: @RDFozz - sirmikeofmitchell.com/files/gimgs/19_sbunny.jpg - Likely [Ralphie from A Christmas Story](http://www.liketotally80s.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ralphie-christmas-story-bunny-suit.jpg)

Comment: @uhoh was the misspelling of "misspelled" intentional?

Comment: They're obviously all Superman.

Comment: @MartianInvader that's it! That's the not-so-"hidden message" perhaps. It's kind-of an homage.

Comment: @SQB [It is. It was](https://www.hometheaterforum.com/community/threads/a-i-question-i-am-i-was.107022/) (sniff) ;-)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I believe the source of this is [this animation posted on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/comments/19gjm9/hero/), which was created by [Mike Mitchell](http://sirmikeofmitchell.com/index.php?/super/).

[image: Animated GIF of heroes(?)]

Specifically, for this T-shirt, from left to right:

1. [Spock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series)
2. [Wonder Woman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Woman)
3. [Ralphie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Christmas_Story) (from *A Christmas Story*)
4. [Mickey Mouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mickey_Mouse)

I found it by searching for `spock wonder woman ralphie mickey mouse`.

Comment: The text on the t-shirt appears to be complete gibberish

Comment: @Valorum okay that makes sense, *faux gibberish* is pretty common here; not correct and not random either.

Comment: This one raises two dozen more questions though...

Comment: @MrLister: The Reddit thread has a list of all of the characters in the animation.

Comment: Great answer, a lot better than the question is answering to. :)

Comment: but who is the base person?

Comment: @AzorAhai this [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/198513/who-are-these-very-unusual-superheroes-on-this-2nd-hand-t-shirt?noredirect=1#comment544728_198513) suggests Superman

Comment: Yes, the base is Superman. Specifically, [this pose](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/49/4e/fb/494efbcde61c3ffe2576a61ba05598be.jpg) from the classic Golden Age Superman. This is not the first such animation; I've seen others. They started off as jokes observing that early comics (and later ones, besides) made little effort to make character's faces look distinctive, so that (e.g.) Clark Kent, Bruce Wayne and Tony Stark would all look the same in their civilian identities, save for costume differences (and the odd mustache/beard here and there). And thus the "X is everyone" meme was born.

Comment: When he turns into the Ghostbuster, does that mean he's wearing blackface?

Answer (score 5):

From left to right:

1. A swole version of Spock from *Star Trek: The Original Series*.
2. A swole version of Wonder Woman from DC comics.
3. A swole version of Arthur from the Tick? Though honestly this could be almost any anthropomorphic rabbit character.
4. Mickey Mouse from Disney. Once again swolified.

Comment: http://sirmikeofmitchell.com/files/gimgs/19_sbunny.jpg - Likely [Ralphie from A Christmas Story](http://www.liketotally80s.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ralphie-christmas-story-bunny-suit.jpg)

Comment: Not sure #3 is the Tick....but that was my first thought too.

Comment: What does "swole" mean?

Comment: Swole = swollen. It's Ameri-English slang - https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/swole

Comment: Arthur?  1. Arthur's costume is white, not pink. 2. Arthur is a *moth*, not a rabbit.  Also, note that the character on the t-shirt is wearing a bunny suit that has built-in bunny slippers, so not quite any anthropomorphic rabbit character. (It's definitely Ralphie, especially with the hair and the glasses.)

Comment: I love the use of swolified as a verb,

Comment: No, [_this_ is Arthur](http://sirmikeofmitchell.com/files/gimgs/19_arthur-copy.jpg).